# Aplicar propiedad a todos los subelementos de un elemento

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, scss

Estoy jugando con Boostrap y CSS y tengo una duda que no consigo revolver, si por ejemplo tengo un `div` con la clase "row" y le pongo el id "row-de-pruebas", y quiero que el atributo `font-size` de todos los elementos sea por ejemplo "medium", tengo este código pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar

```css
#row-de-pruebas {
    font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id"row-de-pruebas">
    <p>hola</p>
    <div>hola 2</div>
</div>
```

Solo consigo hacerlo funcionar si "duplico" el código y creo este CSS:

```css
#row-de-pruebas > div  {
  font-size: medium;
}

#row-de-pruebas > p {
  font-size: medium;
}
```

Y tengo el mismo problema si dentro del `div` pongo un `p`, debo añadir esto:

```css
#row-de-pruebas > div > p {
  font-size: medium;
}
```

Es decir, tengo el problema que una propiedad no la están heredando los elementos que hay debajo de ella.

Comment: ¿por que no generas una clase y la incluyes en `p` y `div`?

Comment: @phpMyGuel la edición que has hecho corrige el problema. Era un fallo tipográfico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenías un error tipográfico `id"row-de-pruebas"` añadiendo un `=` se soluciona, si el problema persite puede ser debido a la jerarquia pero puedes usar [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) para que te lo aplique.

```css
#row-de-pruebas {
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row-de-pruebas">
    <p>hola</p>
    <div>hola 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No hace falta poner `!important` para que esto funcione. El problema era un fallo tipográfico (faltaba un `=`) que se corrigió en tu respuesta. Si quitas el `!important` el texto de dentro también se verá a 50px.

Comment: cierto, edito respuesta